# How to deserialize JSON using parameterized constructor with nested objects

Tags: json.net

I'm trying to deserialize this JSON using Newtonsoft.Json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "New cheese 1",
    "inputs": {
      "cheeseNumber": "01"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "New Cheese 2",
    "inputs": {
      "cheeseNumber": "02"
    }
  }
]
```

using a parameterized constructors so that I can keep the setters private.  I'm deserializing using:

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(cheeseFilePath))
{
    var json = r.ReadToEnd();
    var cheeses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cheese>>(json);
    foreach (var cheese in cheeses)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cheese.ToString());
    }
}
```

and these are my classes:

```
using System;

namespace ReadingJsonIntoObjects
{
    public class Cheese
    {
        //private Cheese(string name,
        //    Inputs inputs)
        //{
        //    this.Name = name;
        //    this.Inputs = inputs;
        //}

        public String Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("Cheese: '{0}' - Inputs: CheeseNumber: {1}", 
                this.Name, this.Inputs.CheeseNumber);
        }

        public Inputs Inputs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Inputs
    {
        public Inputs(string cheeseNumber)
        {
            this.CheeseNumber = cheeseNumber;
        }

        public String CheeseNumber { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

With the constructor commented-out, it works.  But that requires the setter for Inputs to be public and I want it to be private.  With it marked private and the ctor uncommented, I get

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to find a constructor to use for type ReadingJsonIntoObjects.Cheese. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path '[0].name', line 3, position 11.

The class has only one constructor with arguments but it's not recognized.  Is there a way to mark it private and still have it correctly deserialized?

Answer (score 0):

Json.Net prefers to use the default (without parameters) constructor on an object, if you want to use non-default constructor you can add `[JsonConstructor]`  attribute to the constructor that you want Json.Net to call.

like this

```
[JsonConstructor]
    private Cheese(string name, Inputs inputs)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Inputs = inputs;
    }
```